# Chrome not rendering image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Images won't render initially in Chrome, but if I resize the page they appear, or if I change any arbitrary css property. React version is 0.13.1.

It doesn't appear to be a cache issue.

Here is my code.

```
var ios_store = "/images/android-app.png";
var google_store = "/images/ios-app.png";

<div className="app-store-container">
  <img src={google_store} />
  <img src={ios_store} />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a link/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the images in a div with height or width set to 0